# XyPic does not accept targets

Tags: xy-pic

I am trying to typeset an arrow between the middle points of two other arrows. I thought the more canonical choice would have been to give a target to the labels of the two arrows and then draw an arrow between these targets, like

```
\xymatrix{A\ar[r]^{a}="a" & B\ar[r]^{b}="b" &C \ar@{->}@/_1pc/"a";"b"}
```

But all I get is an arrow leaving from C to my label a, and then TeX typeset ;"b", completely ignoring that the semicolon was there to tell it that the arrow should have left from target "b", namely my label b.

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood the problem. It was the French babel package causing trouble, probably interfering with the way TeX understand the character ". Indeed, the same problem occurs when setting the language to Italian or German, it seems that the unique option if one wants Babel is to set it to English. As I write this answer, I actually realize that I am not really sure what is the point of the Babel package...

Comment: No problem. From the user guide: *XY-pic should be loaded after files that change category 
codes like the `german.sty` that makes `"` active.
 Some
styles require that you reset the catcodes for every
diagram, e.g., with `french.sty` you should use the
command `\english` before every `\xymatrix`.*